# Use DHCP to set Failover Cluster IP Address

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, dhcp, failovercluster

I have a Hyper-V Failover Cluster running using manually-configured IP addresses.  On this cluster, among other machines, I have two Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Machines running failover cluster, intended for use in clustering file services.  The 2 Cluster Host machines for the file server receive their IP addresses properly through DHCP.  However, the cluster is NOT able to receive an IP through DHCP.

I find the following error in the cluster log:

Event ID 1240: Cluster IP address resource 'Cluster IP Address' failed to obtain a leased address.

What might be causing this problem?  How can I resolve it?

Comment: Some more info to help:

The DHCP server is running on a different network, but is assigning the addresses for the new failover cluster nodes properly.

Also, when other Hyper-V guests are created and attached to this same network, PXE boots don't work with a DHCP error, however, if the operating system is already installed they are able to obtain an ip address lease from the DHCP server.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly what do you mean by "properly through DHCP"? it's generally a bad idea to use DHCP for servers

Secondly it's a really bad idea to use DHCP for cluster VIPs.

Comment: I mean that the interfaces on the two clustered machines get addresses assigned to them as I would expect by my DHCP server, and that I can see them in the DHCP server leases.

Comment: Would you care to expand on why its a bad idea to use DHCP for cluster VIPs?

Comment: Just do some searching on here for dhcp to see the strength of feeling against using dhcp for servers in general let alone vips.